# HTTP Post message for firebase in Java

Tags: java, http, networking, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a notification from my Java program to Firebase. But I don't know how to do that.

In order to send a notification using curl:

```
# api_key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
   --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
   -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

I want the equivalent of that in Java. I tried the following but it is not correct

```
String rawData =  "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}";
String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode( rawData, "UTF-8" ); 

URL u = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+api_key);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(encodedData.getBytes());
```

Comment: That looks wrong: `conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "api_key");` can you show in detail that you have for `"api_key"? Feel free to replace some characters from your key with dots (so others can't use it), but leave the start and end, so that we can verify completeness/correctness of the format.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The key is like this: AIPOzID_OP....RO

Comment: If that is the literal string you have, you're missing the `key=` in front of it. It should be `conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AIPOzID_OP....RO");`

Comment: I get 400 error, bad request

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I deleted the line `String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode( rawData, "UTF-8" ); ` and it is working now.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why that makes a difference, but good to hear that you got it working.